# How to perform runtime inspections on an object in C?

Tags: c, object, debugging

I have a C program with an object that I don't know much about (it's a `struct`).  I do have the `struct` source code, but am not sure what all the has been populated with at runtime.

If I were to be using Python, I could inspect the object using functions in the built-in [inspect library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) paired with the [Python debugger (`pdb`) library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).

However, with C, I am not sure how to do this.  How can I perform runtime inspections on an object?

---

*Disclaimer*: I am very new to C programming

The code is run on a remote server, and I am using `vim` as my text editor.

Comment: Use a debugger like `gdb`. Since you are using `vim` I'm guessing it's a Linux platform. If not then there will be an equivalent debugger for your platform.

Comment: For those who know C but not Python, could you summarize what you mean by "inspect"?  Do you just mean you want to print out the values of some or all of its members?

Comment: Yeah @NateEldredge basically just print `public` member variables, object type, etc.

Comment: There's no such capability within the language, but as kaylum says, if you can run your program in a debugger, you can do it that way.  Try `ptype foo` and `p foo` in gdb.

Comment: (I mean, obviously you can write by hand a function that does `printf("%d: %s %f\n", obj.a, obj.s, obj.x);` or whatever.  But I assume you wanted to automate it, and the language doesn't provide that.  By the way, from your mention of `public`, are you sure this program is C and not C++?)

Comment: @NateEldredge I am still learning the distinction between C/C++.  I didn't know `public` was for C++, ignore that I said it now (my project is definitely C).  And okay I will try playing around with `gdb`, thank you!